# How could I politely say an HR that I want another position in another state in the same company, after 2 interviews?

Tags: interviewing, career-development, human-resources

I sent an application in this company for a IC designer position to work abroad, but it was rejected. The engineer sent my CV to the HR of my country. I did 2 skype interview, first with only HR, second with HR and 2 engineers; the work is for RF circuit design (less) and test (most). I was invited on site, they spent a lot for the travel so I think they are quiete interested in me.The position is interesting as well for me, but there is another one in the same company but in another state as junior IC designer. I'm REALLY interested in develop a career in that position, and also I'm really interested in working outside my country. How can I say politely that to the HR, without making they upset?
Of course I can wait to be hired and then ask for a carrer change after an year, but is not sure that in a year the position will be opened, and also it's now about 2 years that I got my grade, and since that I have been working for different position but never for the one that interest me, IC designer.

Answer (score 3):

That would be tantamount to telling them you're not interested in the position they have spent money and effort interviewing you for, and instead you want them to do you a favour. Basically I cannot see that working out well for you.

I suggest that you apply separately for the other position and either give up on this one, or follow through with the interviews and make your decision if you actually get an offer. An offer is just an offer you can turn it down.

Comment: yes, is not polite to ask them to do me a favour to push me in the other role, indeed I don't want to do it. I want to remark that even this position is interesting for me (In the past I refused offer for position that didn't fit me), but the other one interesting me more. Also I appreciate how this company threated me during the selection process, I think is a really ethical a good company.

Comment: Apply for the other position by applying for the other position.